# Custom functions to check uniqueness of a field?

Tags: php, validation, yii2

I want to validate an email address that a client submits but I don't want an error to pop up if client submits his own email address
Right now my email validation looks like this:

```php
['email', 'unique', 'targetClass' => Client::class, 'message' => 'This email address is taken']
```

But I would like to be able to pass a function `'unique'` to determine whether I even need to apply the `'unique'` filter, like this:

```php
['email', 'unique', 'unique' => function($value) { /* ... */ }, 'targetClass' => Client::class, 'message' => 'This email address is taken']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the documentation "Forcing A Unique Rule To Ignore A Given ID":
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#rule-unique

`'email' => 'unique:users,email_address,'.$user->id`

**Edit**
For Yii check this documentation:
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-validators-validator#$when-detail

Comment: sorry but this is Laravel, not Yii

Comment: Oh, okay. I was a little confused